# Will my programming question currently posted on CR be OK for SO?

Tags: discussion, scope

Since [my question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/91766/initializing-local-variable-to-generic-interface) includes working code I thought it belonged to Code Review and posted it there.
Apparently it was deemed too *hypothetical* for their taste.

Would it be OK to move it to SO?

Comment: Seems to open ended for SO.  What problems are you having with the code?  If you have a specific problem with the code, then solving that problem would be on topic on SO.

Comment: Well, their close policy said: _" Pseudocode, hypothetical code, or stub code should be replaced by a concrete example."_ I'd suspect they want kind of [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as we're requiring actually on SO.

Comment: I'm asking if my solution to use concrete class upfront instead of run-time identification via Reflection is a sound and safe approach.

Comment: Since I actually ran this code I do have a small `main()` that would make it *executable*.  I honestly thought that part would muddle the issue.

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes, you are.  That's, *not* a specific question.  "Is there literally *anything* in the whole wide world that could go wrong when I do <this thing>?" is not a specific question.  It's a *very* broad question.  Something like, "When I use <this thing> it does Foo when I want it to Bar, how do I make this thing Bar?" is a much more specific question.

Comment: @Servy - My question is: `I do not see anything wrong with this approach.  Am I missing something more or less obvious?`  If I knew **what** might be wrong, I would've researched it on my own.

Comment: @PM77-1 Why does that make the question *not* be too broad?

Comment: You might need to reword the question a bit, but it may be more accepted at the Programmers site: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Cypher It'd going to have all of the same problems on programmers that it would on SO.

Comment: You might want to give this a read: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/. This question as it stands seems to fall into the "What kind of questions should I not ask here?" category because it's very hypothetical. If you can make the question more specific (see the comment on your CR question), you may have better luck.

Answer (score 5):

The reason why you can't find the right place to post your question is because your problem is not well defined.

You have posted some code, that returns the union of all the elements in two sets. But the **specification** of the method is not there (see my comment on your question: is the returned set supposed to be of a specific type? sorted in a specific order? throw an exception in some cases? etc.).

Once you have defined that specification, your question could evolve into two things:

- either the code you have behaves as specified and the question may be posted on CR if you would like people to comment on how to improve it
- ot it does not in which case there is a bug and you could post a question on SO explaining why it doesn't do what you expect, or, even better, you could include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the faulty behaviour.

Comment: I think what irked them was my first phrase that erroneously gave an impression that I just copied a part of someone else's code.  I'm reworking the question now.

Comment: I've modified the original question. Is it better now?